# Is Ajax "update" ok after "render" was false?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Can I send Ajax "update" commands to JSF components that have not been rendered due to render option previously set to false:

```
render="#{BackingBean.doRender}"
```

doRender is set to `true` just before "update" has been sent.

Is this the right way?

I am using PrimeFaces and one component does not show after `update` even `doRender` is set to true in the meantime.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The ajax update works by JavaScript with the JSF-generated HTML DOM tree (as the webbrowser has retrieved). If a JSF component is not rendered, then it does not appear in the HTML DOM tree at all and hence JavaScript can't find anything to update.

You need to update a parent component instead, which is *always* rendered.

E.g.

```
<h:panelGroup id="foo">
    <h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.rendered}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

with

```
<p:commandButton ... update="foo" />
```

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks very much for such a clear answer. I am using PrimeFaces, and component to use for this kind of problems is `<p:outputPanel>` as the PrimeFaces documentation clearly states.

Comment: You're welcome. The only advantage of `<p:outputPanel>` is that it can also be auto-updated on every single ajax request without being explicitly specified in `update` of an action. This does not immediately seem to be the case in your particular case.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Somehow, I just like using as much as I can from PrimeFaces; to be honest I don't know it that makes any sense, but I just like to have less and less `<h:` in my code and more of the `<p:`.

Comment: I like to use the right tool for the job, without any unnecessary overhead if possible.